# Add text inside itemize and enumerate without indent

Tags: margins, indentation

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\toleftmargin}[1]{?????}


\begin{document}
    \toleftmargin{This text should be on the left margin and already is}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text

        This text should be still indented

        \toleftmargin{This text should be on the left margin}

        \item Text
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Text

            This text should be still indented

            \toleftmargin{This text should be on the left margin}

            \item Text
        \end{itemize}
        \item Text
    \end{itemize}
    \toleftmargin{This text should be on the left margin and already is}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Text

        This text should be still indented

        \toleftmargin{This text should be on the left margin}

        \item Text
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Text

            This text should be still indented

            \toleftmargin{This text should be on the left margin}

            \item Text

        \end{enumerate}
        \item Text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I'm supposed to create the command `\toleftmargin` that brings the text to the left margin by removing the indentation of the text given in parameter.

I don't know how to proceed. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are there lines in the lists which  should remain indented?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the circumstances, I figured a code fragment would do.  Note, you need at least one `\par` and the second is ignored.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\toleftmargin}[1]{\par\noindent\hspace{-\@totalleftmargin}\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{#1}}
\makeatother
```